# Можно ли залить свой сайт в интернет без хостинга?

Tags: хостинг

Может комп выступать в роли серва?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Большинство интернет провайдеров (если не все) предоставляют платно услуги выделенного IP и доменного имени, что как раз и является базой для размещения своего сайта на своем компьютере...

Comment: А как-нибудь бесплатно возможно?

Comment: Если только эти услуги входят в ваш пакет подключения (что мало вероятно)... Провайдер ВолгаТелеком (теперь уже РосТелеком) Нижний Новгород - цена услуги что-то около 300р в месяц. Т.е в любом случае либо вы платите своему провайдеру + проходите курсы администрирования и настройки сервера и пр. пр. пр. или вы платите хостинг провайдеру за качественный хостинг. Ну или как все - любой (условно)бесплатный хостинг, что является самым оптимальным выбором человеку не сильно посвященному в ознакомительных целях=)

Comment: dyndns смотрите, полезная штука :)  
Позволяет грубо говоря сделать из динамического IP статический, потом сможете сайт поставить на свой ПК.

Comment: @teveakea знаком, работает только если IP внешний (за маршрутизатором - не работает). Проверить можно, подняв денвер и попросив кого-нибудь посмотреть сайт).

Comment: есть Apache. Страничка нужна на некоторое время. Денвер ставил но не получалось(((

Comment: Поставьте какую-нибудь страничку, чтоб она открывалась по `http://127.0.0.1/`, потом зайдите на <a href="http://2ip.ru/">2ip.ru</a> и вбейте ваш внешний IP в адресную строку. Если видите страничку - идите на <a href="http://http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/">dyn.com</a>, регайтесь, качайте клиент и будет вам счастье. Если не видете - придется искать другой способ.

Comment: плс помоги, я скачал все зарегался. А че дальше? Я первый раз свой сайт выкладываю...Нубас я ))

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то, сервер это компьютер, только  высокопроизводительный :) А сайт так или иначе где-то должен находиться (не на флэшке естественно), а услуга хостинга создает ему сетевой адрес и предоставляет доступ со стороны клиентов. Если подразумевалось: можно ли найти бесплатный хостинг для своего сайта - ответ утвердительный.

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать в качестве хостинга свой комп. Cайт будет доступен по вашему ip.

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт простой, то можно попробовать захостить на Дропбоксе через [Droppages](http://droppages.com/)

Файлы как раз буду хранится на компе